# Displaying relations in grails f:table

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, gsp

I wonder if there is a way to read relation fields when using the f:table plugin

```
<f:table collection="${purchaseInvoiceList}" properties="${['registry.number', 'provider', 'dateCreated']}"/>
```

Using registry.number throws an exception.

> Invalid property of bean class is not readable or has an invalid
>   getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter
>   type of the setter?

I got it to work by adding getters in the PurchaseInvoice class:

```
def getNumber(){
    return registry.getNumber()
}
```

but I do not like to add methods to the model for something that only the view show be concerned with.